# Do Mages get the Ritual Casting feat by default?

Tags: dnd-4e, class-feature, wizard, rituals

Trying to figure out whether or not Mages (aka Wizard (Mage)) get the ritual casting class feature.  Wizards are introduced in Player Handbook 1 and get the class feature on page 158.  Mages are introduced in Heroes of the Fallen Lands on page 192.  Class Features start on page 197.  Nowhere does it state ritual casting as a feature for Mages.

So do I add it because it's something all wizards get or do I not since I am a specialized mage?

Any proof supporting one side or the other would be awesome.  Thanks!

Comment: There is no reference / connection made in Heroes of Fallen Lands to the Wizard class in D&D's 4th edition Player's Handbook. So, I doubt that the Mage is a sub-class / supplement that inherits from the Wizard class. In fact, the class description provided for the Mage in Heroes of Fallen Lands seems defined as a separate class - not just a supplement the Wizard class - since it explicitly redetermines several class features and schools of magic, such as Implement Training (not just Ritual Casting).

Comment: The Mage (aka Wizard (Mage)) is explicitly a Wizard.  The Class Compendium updated the original Wizard to Wizard (Arcanist).  Note that there is also no such thing as a Mage power; all powers printed in HotFL for Mages are "Wizard Attack" or "Wizard Utility".  Wizard (Arcanists)s can take powers from HotFL, and Wizard (Mage)s can take powers from PHB1.

Answer (score 8):

D&D 4e is very explicit about this sort of thing. If it's not listed, you don't get it.